# Is it safe to delete my git directory? Cloned in the wrong location

Tags: git

noob alert: I am learning version control and started a job in a company that uses git.
I did git clone to pull the company code base to my machine, but I pulled it into a wrong directory. 
Can I delete this directory on my machine by issuing a `rm -rf *` or something along those lines and redo the clone to the preferred directory?

I just want to make sure its safe to do this, I dont want to destroy the company's codebase.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It will only delete your local copy.

Having said that, the easier way probably will be to simply move it to the preferred location.

Each git repository is self contained and doesn't care about where it has been cloned to.

Comment: can you tell me how I could possibly destroy the company's codebase? Just want to make sure I dont accidentally do that.. I am nervous about version control and making changes to their code.

Comment: Unless you do a `git push`, all the changes you make are local to your repository. Short of going to the server and deleting the git repository there, you can't destroy their codebase.